# Can't clear the form after successful completion

Tags: php

Hi I have a "Sticky" form that after successful completion I want to clear the fields
I tried placing the $_POST = array(); in different sections of the IF statements,

This is the entire file, it is a form that get's sent to itself and records what you wrote in a file outside the webroot

Thanks for any help

```
  <!-- BEGIN CHANGABLE CONTENT -->

<?php require('templates/header.html') ?>
<div id="main" role="main">
<h1>Welcome to the site</h1>
<h2>Please fill out the form</h2>
<p>Register and become a member!<br />Members enjoy newsletters and free swag courtesy of Tony Browns Design</p>

<form action="index.php" method='post' id='login_form'>
    <legend><h2>Registration Form</h2></legend>
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name='fname' id='fname' size='20' 
                value="<?php if (isset($_POST['fname'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']);} ?>" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name='lname' id='lname' size='20' 
                value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lname'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']);} ?>"  />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="text" name='email' id='email' size='20' 
                value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fname'])) {echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);} ?>"  />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="quotes" class='move-top'>Quote: </label>
            <textarea name="quotes" id="quote" cols="22" rows="8">Enter your quotation here.</textarea><br />
        </div>
         <div>
            <input type="submit" value='submit' />
         </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>



<?php 

$file   =   '../quotes_from_users.txt';

//Check if form is submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (empty($_POST['fname']) && (empty($_POST['lname']) && (empty($_POST['email'])))) {
        echo '<p style="color: #d00; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #200; font-size: 1.4em;">You need to fill in the all the fields!</p>';
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['quotes']) && ($_POST['quotes'] != 'Enter your quotation here.') ) {
        if (is_writable($file)) {
            file_put_contents($file, $_POST['quotes'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

            echo '<p style="color= #cf5 font-size: 1.4em;">Your quote has been stored.</p>';
            $_POST = array();

        } else {
            echo '<p style="color: #d00; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #200;">Your quote could not be stored due to a systems error, sorry about that!</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p style="color: #d00; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #200; font-size: 1.4em;">Please enter a quote!</p>';
    }



}


?>
        <?php require('templates/footer.html'); ?>
    </div>
<!-- END CHANGABLE CONTENT -->
```

Comment: Can you include the form file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems flawed, if you only post a quote, it will get saved with this code.

It should be something like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  // the next line has changed
  if (empty($_POST['fname']) || (empty($_POST['lname']) || (empty($_POST['email'])))) {
      echo '<p style="color: #d00; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #200; font-size: 1.4em;">You need to fill in the all the fields!</p>';
  }
  else    // added
  {
    if (!empty($_POST['quotes']) && ($_POST['quotes'] != 'Enter your quotation here.') ) {
        if (is_writable($file)) {
            file_put_contents($file, $_POST['quotes'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

            echo '<p style="color= #cf5 font-size: 1.4em;">Your quote has been stored.</p>';
            // only empty $_POST on a successful submission
            $_POST = array();


        } else {
            echo '<p style="color: #d00; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #200;">Your quote could not be stored due to a systems error, sorry about that!</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p style="color: #d00; text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #200; font-size: 1.4em;">Please enter a quote!</p>';
    }
  }
}
```

That is assuming that your form gets added in `templates/footer.html`

Comment: so all you are changing is the AND into an OR, I tried your solution and it doesn't clear the fields, the form works except for fields not cleared

Comment: oh the file gets sent to $file ../user_quotes.txt

Comment: @pixel 67 No, that is because the form is already filled in *before* you process the sent-in form. You need to move the processing part to the top, before you generate the form.

Comment: @jeron lol I can't believe it, I knew it had to be something silly like that, can't believe I did that 0_0 Thanks so much for your time I really appreciate that :)

Comment: Just started really learning this language about a month ago, I love it, really easy to understand and get results done